# How to get my program to read an input escape sequence

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, newline

I am making a discord bot and one of the commands allows the user to send and embed to any channel with whatever text they want, but I want them to be able to start a new line in the body of the embed too. Simply having them type "\n" in their message in the command does, not work, the bot will output that \n in the embed instead of making a new line. Is there an easy way to do this?

Embed:

```js
const sayEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#4d4d4d')
    .setTitle(header.join(' '))
    .setDescription(args.join(' '))
```

The description field is where this is occurring when there is a "\n" in the `args` array it will not make a new line it will simply send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to use `\n`, you can just create a new line when sending the message, and `discord.js` will do all the parsing work for you. I tested this out with my bot:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you, will try this later and mark as a solution once I verify it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

So I made a kind of simple DIY sort of thing. (LOL, actually I made this as I saw the question, took like 5 mins.)
It allows you to disect a message using the operator `|` (The one below BackSpace).
I tried using this in an `eval` command, so I'm sure it works.
[image]

The codes are:

```
// Creating array variables so it doesn't return undefined when we try to `.concat()` it.
let sentences = [];
let temp = [];
// Loops every args
for(l=0;l<args.length;l++) {
  // Adding the args as an array to the `temp` variable.
  temp = temp.concat(argss[l])
  // If we meet `|` which is a sentence separator.
  if (args[l] === "|") {
    // Join the `temp` array, making it a sentence while removing the `|` operator.
    sentences = sentences.concat(temp.join(' ').slice(0, -2));
    // Resetting `temp` to reset the saved sentence and start a new one.
    temp = [];
  }
}
```

Using `.join(' ')` will not work since it returns a string from an array, and therefore joining `\n` cannot be used.
The above method may be more efficient. They use a command such as:

```
// Say prefix is `.` and the command is `embed`
.embed <header> | <content> | <title1> | <sentence1> | <title2> | <sentence2> |
```

and you will get `sentences[0]`, `sentences[1]`, `sentences[2]`, `sentences[3]`, `sentences[4]`, `sentences[5]` respectively. You can then add this to your embed.
This will also allow multi string input, instead of a single args. Don't forget the `|` at the end since without it, it will ignore the whole last sentence.

```
const sayEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#4d4d4d')
  .setTitle(sentences[0]) // <header>
  .setDescription(sentences[1]) // <content>
  .addField(sentences[2], sentences[3]) // <title1> <sentence1>
  .addField(sentences[4], sentences[5]) // <title2> <sentence2>
  // The more you add, the more it'll allow, you'll have to set it yourself.
```

**TL;DR:** A simpler answer:

```
sentences = args.join(" ").split(" | ");
```

Sorry, I tend to do things the hard way a lot.

Comment: It seems that I do tend to do things the hard way, @Lioness100 's answer is simpler, but mine allows more flexibility, either one works.

Comment: Instead of using a `for` loop, you can just use the [`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). [`JSfiddle` example](https://jsfiddle.net/5d7sch4g/)

Comment: Well, `sentences = args.join(" ").split(" | ")` works just as well I guess. I spent like 10 mins on this without reading anything xd.